# What's exactly meaning of "Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x5937abd0 (code=2)" on Android platform?

Tags: android, crash

What's exactly meaning of "Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x5937abd0 (code=2)"?

The backtrace and stack info are as follow:

```
12-23 17:43:37.904 F/libc    (16421): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x5937abd0 (code=2), thread 16490 (thread-pool-2)
12-23 17:43:38.035 I/DEBUG   (  145): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-23 17:43:38.035 I/DEBUG   (  145): Revision: '0'
12-23 17:43:38.035 I/DEBUG   (  145): pid: 16421, tid: 16490, name: thread-pool-2  >>> com.android.camera <<<
12-23 17:43:38.035 I/DEBUG   (  145): signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 5937abd0
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     r0 58068810  r1 25100001  r2 5937abd0  r3 00000000
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     r4 4cacd6f8  r5 58068a68  r6 00000003  r7 58cf1d18
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     r8 58defab4  r9 58cf1d0c  sl 25100001  fp 58defacc
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     ip 4f686e17  sp 58defaa4  lr 4164b490  pc 4f686e1c  cpsr 800f0030
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d0  0032003300390031  d1  0032003400350037
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d2  0013000b00050005  d3  0013001300130013
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d4  00130013000d0009  d5  0013001300130013
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d6  0013001300130013  d7  0013001300130013
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d16 0039003100340031  d17 0035003700320033
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d18 0013001300130013  d19 0013001300130013
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d20 0013001300130013  d21 0013001300130013
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d22 0013001300130013  d23 0013001300130013
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d24 00de001a00dc3a78  d25 00e18b5e00dfc5bc
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d26 0000000900000008  d27 0000000b0000000a
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d28 0000000400000004  d29 0000000400000004
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     d30 ffffa7e6ffffa7e6  d31 ffffa7e6ffffa7e6
12-23 17:43:38.365 I/DEBUG   (  145):     scr 68000012
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145): backtrace:
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #00  pc 00018e1c  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #01  pc 0001e48c  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #02  pc 0005c967  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+174)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #03  pc 000278a0  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #04  pc 0002fb98  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #05  pc 0002ca50  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #06  pc 00076dd7  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+566)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #07  pc 00076edd  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #08  pc 00066e3b  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #09  pc 0000d228  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #10  pc 0000d3c4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145): stack:
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa64  58068810  [anon:libc_malloc]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa68  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa6c  00000007  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa70  00020bdf  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa74  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa78  4caced90  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa7c  4f68b901  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa80  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa84  25000001  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa88  4caced90  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa8c  58068a68  [anon:libc_malloc]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa90  00000003  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa94  58cf1cfc  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa98  58defab4  [stack:16490]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defa9c  58cf1cec  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defaa0  42002120  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #00  58defaa4  4cacd6f8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defaa8  58068a68  [anon:libc_malloc]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defaac  4164b490  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #01  58defab0  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defab4  58068a68  [anon:libc_malloc]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defab8  58cf1d0c  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defabc  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defac0  58068a78  [anon:libc_malloc]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defac4  42002120  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-zygote (deleted)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defac8  00000001  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defacc  4168996b  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+178)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):     #02  58defad0  58cf1d0c  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defad4  41df1791  /system/framework/core.odex
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defad8  4f686e17  /system/lib/libjavacore.so
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defadc  58068a78  [anon:libc_malloc]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defae0  400df384  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defae4  4caced90  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defae8  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defaec  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defaf0  00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defaf4  41ff63a8  [heap]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defaf8  fffffea0  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defafc  41ff63a8  [heap]
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defb00  fffffea0  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defb04  0000003a  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defb08  4170b6e0  /system/vendor/lib/libdvm.so
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          58defb0c  0000003a  
12-23 17:43:38.375 I/DEBUG   (  145):          ........  ........
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145): memory near r0:
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     580687f0 0000003e 57d24e80 00000001 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068800 00000004 7fffffff 00000028 00000023  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068810 41704444 00000000 00000014 58068a68  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068820 00000000 581a0d98 58068910 00000013  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068830 00000000 00000000 00000010 00000033  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068840 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068850 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068860 3f800000 00000010 6c6f7072 00000033  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068870 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068880 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58068890 3f800000 00000010 00000030 00000033  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     580688a0 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     580688b0 58df2008 58e23008 00010000 58e34008  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     580688c0 5823bf88 5823bf58 612e6d6f 00000043  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     580688d0 002f0184 01300130 11110909 11090909  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     580688e0 09090911 09091111 09111109 01090909  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145): memory near r1:
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     250fffe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     250ffff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     25100090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     251000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     251000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     251000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     251000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145): memory near r2:
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937abb0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937abc0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937abd0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937abe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937abf0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac10 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac20 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac30 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac40 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac50 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac60 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac70 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac80 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937ac90 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145):     5937aca0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
12-23 17:43:38.385 I/DEBUG   (  145): 

12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145): memory near ip:
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686df4 00000000 1004f89d b1019b00 6013ba1b  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e04 f89d4770 88103000 ba40b10b b200b280  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e14 b5304770 300cf89d 68556814 4629b13b  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e24 ba24ba09 46202200 ea424605 46200401  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e34 bd304629 3000f89d b1036810 4770ba00  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e44 f89db530 4614500c e8bdb91d f00e4030  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e54 2b02bff1 fb92d105 e8bdf2f3 f7ff4030  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e64 2b04bf66 fb92d105 e8bdf2f3 f7ff4030  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e74 2b08bf74 fb92d105 e8bdf2f3 f7ff4030  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e84 bd30bf78 41f0e92d 990db086 22004616  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e94 46984604 90039f0f 92059104 f7f8b911  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686ea4 e002fdf6 fbd8f7f9 9b059005 6820b1e3  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686eb4 f8d04631 22005378 47a84620 b1984605  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686ec4 1040f89d 9b0e9a05 0008fb07 18d19100  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686ed4 9a0c463b ffb4f7ff 46206827 737cf8d7  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686ee4 462a4631 47b82300 f7f9a803 b006f89e  
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.405 I/DEBUG   (  145): memory near sp:
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defa84 25000001 4caced90 58068a68 00000003  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defa94 58cf1cfc 58defab4 58cf1cec 42002120  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defaa4 4cacd6f8 58068a68 4164b490 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defab4 58068a68 58cf1d0c 00000000 58068a78  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defac4 42002120 00000001 4168996b 58cf1d0c  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defad4 41df1791 4f686e17 58068a78 400df384  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defae4 4caced90 00000000 00000000 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defaf4 41ff63a8 fffffea0 41ff63a8 fffffea0  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb04 0000003a 4170b6e0 0000003a 4170b6e0  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb14 58068a68 42fdbd28 42fdbd28 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb24 4169495b 4170ba5c 0000003a 4170b6e0  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb34 42fdbd28 0000003a 41657894 0000000c  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb44 58068a68 42fdbd08 0000002a 00000015  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb54 00000015 400df384 0000003a 41ff8950  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb64 416b0807 00000018 41657894 4170b6e0  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     58defb74 4164b600 416943bd 5c1909e0 00009c40  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145): code around pc:
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686dfc b1019b00 6013ba1b f89d4770 88103000  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e0c ba40b10b b200b280 b5304770 300cf89d  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e1c 68556814 4629b13b ba24ba09 46202200  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e2c ea424605 46200401 bd304629 3000f89d  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e3c b1036810 4770ba00 f89db530 4614500c  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e4c e8bdb91d f00e4030 2b02bff1 fb92d105  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e5c e8bdf2f3 f7ff4030 2b04bf66 fb92d105  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e6c e8bdf2f3 f7ff4030 2b08bf74 fb92d105  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e7c e8bdf2f3 f7ff4030 bd30bf78 41f0e92d  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e8c 990db086 22004616 46984604 90039f0f  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686e9c 92059104 f7f8b911 e002fdf6 fbd8f7f9  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686eac 9b059005 6820b1e3 f8d04631 22005378  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686ebc 47a84620 b1984605 1040f89d 9b0e9a05  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686ecc 0008fb07 18d19100 9a0c463b ffb4f7ff  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686edc 46206827 737cf8d7 462a4631 47b82300  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4f686eec f7f9a803 b006f89e 81f0e8bd b087b5f0  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145): code around lr:
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b470 3497c004 3488c004 3afffff9 e2888004  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b480 eafffff9 e899000c e59bc00c e12fff3c  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b490 e3560000 159bc010 e24bd014 188c0003  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b4a0 e8bd8bc0 e1a0ce22 e59b6008 e2866001  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b4b0 e3a02000 e4d6c001 e35c0000 0a000007  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b4c0 e2822001 e35c0044 135c004a 1afffff8  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b4d0 e3120001 12822001 02822002 eafffff4  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b4e0 e2522002 43b02000 0affffe5 e04dd102  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b4f0 e3cdd004 e1a07009 e1a0800d e59b6008  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b500 e2866001 e2877008 e4d6c001 e35c0044  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b510 135c004a 0a000004 e4d6c001 e35c0044  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b520 135c004a 02477004 0a000000 e4d6c001  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b530 e35c0000 0affffd2 e35c0044 135c004a  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b540 0a000002 e497c004 e488c004 eafffff6  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b550 e2888007 e497c004 e3c88007 e4972004  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     4164b560 e488c004 e4882004 eaffffef 00000000  
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145): 
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145): memory map around fault addr 5937abd0:
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     592e3000-5935b000 rw- anon_inode:dmabuf
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     59363000-59381000 rw- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.camera/cache/imgcache.idx
12-23 17:43:38.415 I/DEBUG   (  145):     59381000-59546000 rw- /dev/zero (deleted)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of errors usually happens when something went wrong in the native part of the API you are using (Shared Object) which is written in C or C++. Or perhaps if you are writing your own native library using [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/) and there is a problem in it.

A signal is a software interrupt delivered to a process. The operating system uses signals to report exceptional situations to an executing program. Some signals report errors such as references to invalid memory addresses (SIGSEGV); others report asynchronous events, such as disconnection of a phone line.

What you had is SIGBUS which is you can find more information about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error). And you can know more about signals from [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_21.html) and all the types of it.